# Possible to position elements along a curve using javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, styles, curve

I am working on a design where I would like to position header elements along a curve.  Example:

[image]

Typically I would do this manually using CSS, but in this case there can be a dynamic number of items.

I'm curious if anyone knows of a way to place a dynamic number of items along a curve?  I'm guessing it would require a way of specifying an equation that defines what the curve should be (notice that the curve above peaks right of center...) and then place items spaced evenly on that.

Has anyone done this before?  Any recommendations on where to start?

Comment: One thing that might help is [Lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com). It won't do the positioning but it might make it easier to manage the text.

Comment: The answer depends a lot on what *kind* of curve you want to use. Circular arc? Parabola? Hyperbola?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to specify a curve is using a Bezier cubic.

[image]

```
function bez3(x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, t)
{
    var x01 = x0 + t*(x1 - x0);
    var y01 = y0 + t*(y1 - y0);
    var x12 = x1 + t*(x2 - x1);
    var y12 = y1 + t*(y2 - y1);
    var x23 = x2 + t*(x3 - x2);
    var y23 = y2 + t*(y3 - y2);

    var x012 = x01 + t*(x12 - x01);
    var y012 = y01 + t*(y12 - y01);
    var x123 = x12 + t*(x23 - x12);
    var y123 = y12 + t*(y23 - y12);

    return {x: x012 + t*(x123 - x012),
            y: y012 + t*(y123 - y012)};
}
```

The curve starts at `t=0, (x0, y0)` tangent toward `(x1, y1)` and arrives at `t=1, (x3, y3)` coming tangent from `(x2, y2)`.

For `t=0` the function returns the starting point `(x0, y0)`, for `t=1` the function returns the ending point `(x3, y3)`. Values of `t` between 0 and 1 are points along the curve (they're smoothly but not equally spaced however). You can think to `t` as a "time" parameter of a point moving along the curve.

Following [this link](http://raksy.dyndns.org/bezier.html) is possible to see an interactive version implemented in javascript/canvas (the example uses letters A, B, C and D instead of 0, 1, 2 and 3 to mark the different points).

Comment: You have a funny definition of the word "simple".

Comment: Ok, I understand what the x/y values represent, but what is `t` in relation to the graph above?  What does it define that `x0,y0`/`x3,y3` do not?  Is `t` always a value between 0 and 1?

Comment: @mblase75: Simple means that it's easy to choose the control points and get a smooth curve with the shape you want. Indeed bezier cubic are often used in vector drawing programs for this very reason. The formula is also rather simple... they are just linear interpolations.

Comment: @AbeMiessler: t=0 is the start, t=1 is the end. values between 0 and 1 will return points on the curve (e.g. t=0.5 will be roughly in the middle of the curve). If you want 10 points on the curve just use 1/11, 2/11 ... 10/11. Note however they will not necessarily be perfectly equally spaced (the curve may "accelerate" and "decelerate").

Answer (score 1):

You could using the formula of a curve and absolute positioning. Write a function, which given X will return you Y, make that function return Y as something that will be curvy (look into your old geometry or trig books). Now, iterate through your elements, giving a certain gap between the X values of your elements. X = left, Y = top.

See http://fancythought.blogspot.com/2011/06/love-formula-heart-shaped-curvy-graph.html for formula...

You could also use relative positioning on a parent element to allow for better placement (relative will make the absolute elements position relative to the parent).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the function @6502's mentioned to create a jQuery plugin that I am using for this.  Since number of elements that must be placed on the curve varies dynamically, having the plugin that is applied to a selector works nicely.  It also assists with generating the equation of the curve.

You can find it here:

- http://plugins2.jquery.com/project/jCurvy
- http://jCurvy.com